Uniqueness of solutions of high-order differential equations
I was quite confused about Converse to Wronskian Condition ODEs
" $y(x_0) = y'(x_0) = \cdots = y^{(n-1)}(x_0) = 0$ then the result follows from a contradiction of the uniqueness theorem, since y=0 is also a solution. " 
When defining solutions to higher-order differential equations, do we assume that we only consider solutions that satisfy the theorems of existence and uniqueness of solutions? 
I'm pretty stuck at this point. Thanks for everyone's help !
